# How can I get Lottie animations to work on real devices?

Tags: ios, swift, lottie

I've implemented a Lottie animation in my iOS app. On my real iPhone 6s+ the first frame of the animation appears, but then does not animate. I ran the same code on an iPhone 6s emulator and it animated in a loop like I wanted it to. Can anyone help me figure out why the animation isn't working on real devices?

I have made sure that animations can run on my real device (Reduce Motion is turned off in Accessibility)

I downgraded my Lottie pod to version 3.0.3 because some people were saying the newest version has issues, but that didn't help.

Here I'm setting up the view:

```swift
let animationView = AnimationView(name: "my_animation")
animationView.loopMode = LottieLoopMode.loop
```

Here's how I play the animation in the controller

```swift
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        animationView.play()
    }
```

Comment: All of a sudden the animation started working on my real device. It worked for a few hours yesterday. When I came back to it today, it had stopped working again. Something weird is going on